# how to covert JSONObject to another Required JSONObect by mapping AccountId using java

Tags: java, arrays, json

**My result of JSONObject to convert as follows bellow code and have searched for many this how to convert using java but I converted that **

```
 {
            "result": {
                "accountnames": [{
                    "accountName": "Hari",
                    "accountId": 878488
                }, {
                    "accountName": "ravi",
                    "accountId": 878487
                }],
                "sales": [{
                    "accountSales": "89",
                    "accountId": 878488
                }, {
                    "accountName": "98",
                    "accountId": 878487
                }],
                "countResult": [{
                    "accountResult": "945",
                    "accountId": 878488
                }, {
                    "accountResult": "9452",
                    "accountId": 878489
                }]
            }
        }
```

*and this is where the sample code to be converted *

```
{
    "result": [{
            "accountName": "Hari",
            "accountSales": "89",
            "accountResult": "945",
            "accountId": 878488
        },
        {
            "accountName": "ravi",
            "accountSales": "98",
            "accountId": 878487
        },
        {
            "accountResult": "9452",
            "accountId": 878489
        }
    ]
}
My required JSON data has to be formatted as below
```

Comment: Hello, I believe you are missing some of your question. I would suggest deleting this question before it gets downvoted for not having a clear problem statement, as to help avoid that you don't get a question ban, then finish editing and fixing the question. You'll be able to undelete the question after that.

Comment: I'm guessing you hit post before you finished typing?

Comment: i can't see anything

Comment: You forgot to include the two structures in the question. When you update it, don't forget to include your current code too.

Comment: Thanks for including missing details in your question! However, SO is not a coding service. Please, update your question with the code you tried, and tell us what didn't work, why, what was the expected output and what happened instead. If you got any error, please include the full stack trace too.

Comment: What json library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group all the elements by `accountId`. You can use something like this depending on the json library that you are using.

Initialize the json object:

```
JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject resultJson = rootJson.getJSONObject("result");
```

Create a map to hold the objects by `accountId`:

```
Map<String, JSONObject> accountIds = new HashMap<>();
```

Then iterate for each key in the json, then for each element in the arrays and then for each property of the object inside the json:

```
Iterator mainKeys = resultJson.keys();
while (mainKeys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) mainKeys.next();
    JSONArray array = resultJson.getJSONArray(key);

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length(); index++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(index);
        if (object.has("accountId")) {
            String accountId = object.get("accountId").toString();
            JSONObject accum = accountIds
                    .computeIfAbsent(accountId, (k) -> new JSONObject());

            // depending on the json impl you can use putAll or similar
            Iterator objKeys = object.keys();
            while (objKeys.hasNext()) {
                String property = (String) objKeys.next();
                accum.put(property, object.get(property));
            }

        } else {
            // does not have account id, ignore or throw
        }
    }
}
```

Finally create the json file and add the elements to the `JSONArray`:

```
JSONObject finalJson = new JSONObject();
finalJson.put("result", new JSONArray(accountIds.values()));
System.out.println(finalJson.toString());
```

(*note: the json has an error in sales array `accountName` instead of `accountSales`*)

Comment: can i know why you added json in                                                  "JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject(json);"                                                                                        and that is that mean.

Comment: There is where you parse the json. The variable `json` is a string that contains the json

Comment: You're wecome .